# React state isn't updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

State isn't updating. I am trying to create the edit function to make edits on posted comments. When the submit button is clicked, nothing changes on the front end. After I refresh the page the changes appear. I can't seem to find where the problem is.

Content.js

```
// handle edit comments
    const editChat = (newComment) => {
        const updatedChatList = chats.map(chat => {
            if (topic.id === newComment.id) {
                return newComment
            } else {
                return chat;
            }
        });
        setChats(updatedChatList);
    }
```

ChatCard.js

```
function ChatCard({ chat, topic, deleteComment, editChat }) {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { id } = chat;
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
    // const openEditMode = () => setEditMode(editMode => !editMode);

    const deleteClick = () => {
        fetch(`/topics/${topic.id}/chats/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
        })
        deleteComment(id)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <p><strong>{ chat.user.username }:</strong> { chat.content }</p>
            </ul>
            {user && user.username === chat.user.username && (
                <div className="chat-btn">
                <button className="delete-btn" onClick={deleteClick}>Delete</button>
                <button className="edit-btn" onClick={() => setEditMode(editMode => !editMode)}>Edit</button>
                </div>
            )}
            { editMode && <ChatEdit chat={chat} topic={topic} editChat={editChat} editMode={editMode} setEditMode={setEditMode} /> }
        </div>
    )
}
```

ChatEdit.js

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { ErrorsContext } from "../context/ErrorsContext";
import Errors from "../errors/Errors";

function ChatEdit({ chat, topic, editChat, editMode, setEditMode }) {
    const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorsContext);
    const [content, setContent] = useState(chat.content);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const editComment = {
            content: content
        }
        fetch(`/topics/${topic.id}/chats/${chat.id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: { 
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(editComment)
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.errors) {
                setErrors(data.errors)
            } else {
                editChat(data)
                setErrors([])
                setEditMode(!editMode)
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <form className="post-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="new-post">
            <textarea className="chat-textarea" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Write your comment." value={content} onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)} /><br/>
            <button type="submit">SEND</button>
            </div>
            <Errors />
        </form>
    )
}

export default ChatEdit;
```

I am trying to get the edited comment to update once I submit the form. It's updating but not until I refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping function, you're comparing topic.id with `newComment.id`. It should be `chat.id` instead.

```
const editChat = (newComment) => {
  const updatedChatList = chats.map(chat => {
    if (chat.id === newComment.id) { // Compare chat.id with newComment.id
      return newComment;
    } else {
      return chat;
    }
  });
  setChats(updatedChatList);
};
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).